# Need design inputs on data pipeline creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-kinesis

For all AWS experts, i need your help in designing and architecting the big data data pipeline.Below is the scenario:-

I have large .gz extension files in S3 ranging from MB to GB. These are w3c format log files compressed format. Now, I want these files to be ingested in the BigData Pipeline, unzip the data from files and then transform the data into a required columns of data.

Could you all aws experts provide me some design solution using Off the shelf tools or open source tools or any customs tools to achieve the above data pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

According to spark documentation

> All of Spark’s file-based input methods, including textFile, support running on directories, compressed files, and wildcards as well. For example, you can use textFile("/my/directory"), textFile("/my/directory/*.txt"), and textFile("/my/directory/*.gz").

All you have to do is read these to RDD (no need for separate decompression) and you can do any transformation you want to.

```
logsRDD = sc.textFile("s3a://<directory>/*gz")
```

Reference:
https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/81191/spark-210-reading-gz-files-from-an-s3-bucket-or-di.html
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html